# What is the difference between MapRoute and MapPageRoute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is MapPageRoute used only on WebForms while MapRoute for MVC?

Or are these applicable on both WebForms and MVC?

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`MapPageRoute` can be used when mapping a route to a specific .aspx file. `MapRoute` is used to map a route to a controller action.

You can mix both WebForms and MVC in one application and then you would use those two mapping functions to create your routing.

If you look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute.aspx) for `MapPageRoute` it states:

> Provides a way to define routes for Web Forms applications.

Comment: I see, so it just means MapRoute can only be used for MVC as WebForms don't have controllers and actions. While MapPageRoute can be used on both WebForms and MVC

Comment: Almost :) MapRoute is indeed only for MVC because it maps your route to a controller. MapPageRoute is ONLY for WebForms because it map's to an aspx file. So MapPageRoute can't be used for mapping WebForm pages

Comment: Wouter de Kort, your comment above conflicts with itself. You meant to say: "So MapPageRoute can't be used for mapping MVC."

Comment: More specifically MapPageRoute cannot be used on Razor pages - this will get you a runtime error if you try to visit the mapped page: MapPageRoute("", "why", "~/Why.cshtml");